# Simple Java Modulus Question

Tags: java, modulus, type-mismatch

I have the following code:

```
for(int i=0;i<=100;i++) {
            if(i % 11) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
```

I just want the code to print the number if it's divisible by 11. It tells me this though: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The reason you're getting this error is that your condition `i % 11` returns an `int` value, but the `if` statement expects a `boolean`.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn it into a condition like this:

```
if(i % 11 == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if((i % 11) == 0)
```

Should use an `==` operator to check. `i%11` returns an int which cannot be converted to `boolean` by default and the compiler is complaining about it.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
if(i % 11==0) {
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

The `%` operator returns an `int`, whereas `if()` can only check `boolean` values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the modulus is zero (meaning it is divisible by 11):

```
if(i % 11 == 0) //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I've changed your condition):

```
for(int i=0;i<=100;i++) {
        if((i % 11) == 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`if` expression requires a boolean value to be passed as condition.

Try this: `(i % 11) == 0`

Full code:

```
for(int i=0; i<=100; i++) {
    if( (i % 11)==0 ) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```